# DbContext is not getting Disposed on Dispose()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why does my DbContext get not Disposed, if I call `Dispose` on it in Debug Mode?

In release Mode everything is working, but in Debugmode, I see in every iteration of my loop, how the memory increases, and never will be released.

I have used the tool *dotMemory* to make sure it is from `_db`.

It works if I write `_db = null;` after `_db.Dispose();`

---

I have this base class:

```
public abstract class SomeBase : IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContext _db;

    public abstract void Process();

    protected KassenautomatEntities Db
    {
        get { return _db ?? (_db = new MyDbContext); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
            _db = null; //Without this, theContext does not get Disposed in Debug Mode
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get an instance of all Classes that inherit from `SomeBase` using this methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumeratedObjectsOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs) where T : class
{
    return EnumerateTypesOfType<T>().Select(type => (T) Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs));
}

public static IEnumerable<Type> EnumerateTypesOfType<T>() where T : class
{
    return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T))
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));
}
```

And process this in a loop:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var someArray= ReflectionUtility.EnumeratedObjectsOfType<SomeBase>().ToArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
    {
        someArray[i].Process();
        someArray[i].Dispose();
        someArray[i] = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So, why do I need to set '_db' it to null? Shouldn't thee reference be automaticly lost on `someArray[i] = null;`?

Comment: Are you running it _in the debugger_ or _in debug mode_ outside the debugger? The debugger will often keep other handles to things that will prevent effective garbage collection.

Comment: Note also that `Dispose` doesn't immediately release managed memory; it just releases unmanaged resources without waiting for garbage collection.

Comment: In other words, Dispose works. It doesn't do what you thought it did, ie clean memory

Comment: @DStanley I am running it in the debugger (vhost). Even after multiple minutes of just standing in `ReadKey` my Memory Footprint is up to 7 GB, mostly everything from `_db`. Why does `_db = null` work, but `someArray[i] = null` don't?